# SQL Server : group by date time and first_value

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a table of exchange rates in a SQL Azure database, at periods of times.

Such as:

```
  1. USD-AUD, 2015-1-1 00:01, 0.70 
     2. USD-AUD, 2015-1-1 00:02, 0.73  
     3. USD-AUD, 2015-1-1 00:03, 0.69  
     4. USD-AUD, 2015-1-1 00:04, 0.78  
     5. USD-AUD, 2015-1-1 00:05, 0.75
     6. USD-AUD, 2015-1-1 00:06, 0.80

(Pair, DateTime, ExchangeRate)
```

I would like to group in 5min intervals, and show min rate, max rate and the first (row 1) and last (row 5).  So open would be 0.70, high = 0.78, low = 0.69 and close 0.75

I have followed a few threads on here on how to group which have been helpful, but I can't work out how to get "open" and "closes"

```
Select min(price) as low, max(price) as high
from exchangetable
(GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, [Time]),
    DATEPART(MONTH, [Time]),
    DATEPART(DAY, [Time]),
    DATEPART(HOUR, [Time])
    GROUP BY DATEPART(mi, [Time]) % 5
```

Using `FIRST_VALUE` http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2640/sql-server-2012-functions--firstvalue-and-lastvalue/ I get a "not supported on this version of SQL error"

Would a solution be to do join to itself, or a cursor?

Comment: The answers below are valid and correct, but they calculate the 5-minute intervals on the fly. If you have a lot of rows it means that they will be slow. I would consider adding a column and store this time explicitly. So, you would have `2015-01-01 00:00:00` stored in rows for the first 5 minutes, then `2015-01-01 00:05:00` in rows for next 5 minutes and so on. Then you would be able to add appropriate index using this persisted column and make your queries run fast. If you don't have a lot of rows any approach would be OK.

Comment: That FIRST_VALUE link was exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No need for a cursor. Try the following. Note that I had to change your inconsistent column names. Also you need integer division in your GROUP BY not the modulus operator (%). The Open and Close columns are produced by sub selects.

```
SELECT
  DATEPART(YEAR,  e1.[datetime]) AS Year,
  DATEPART(MONTH, e1.[datetime]) AS Month,
  DATEPART(DAY,   e1.[datetime]) AS Day,
  DATEPART(HOUR,  e1.[datetime]) AS Hour,
  DATEPART(mi,    e1.[datetime])/5 AS TimeBracket,
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 
      e2.ExchangeRate 
     FROM 
       exchangetable e2 
     WHERE 
       DATEPART(YEAR,  e1.[datetime])   = DATEPART(YEAR,  e2.[datetime]) AND
       DATEPART(MONTH, e1.[datetime])   = DATEPART(MONTH, e2.[datetime]) AND
       DATEPART(DAY,   e1.[datetime])   = DATEPART(DAY,   e2.[datetime]) AND
       DATEPART(HOUR,  e1.[datetime])   = DATEPART(HOUR,  e2.[datetime]) AND
       DATEPART(MI,    e1.[datetime])/5 = DATEPART(MI,    e2.[datetime])/5
     ORDER BY
       [datetime]     
  ) AS [Open],
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 
      e2.ExchangeRate 
     FROM 
       exchangetable e2 
     WHERE 
       DATEPART(YEAR,  e1.[datetime])   = DATEPART(YEAR,  e2.[datetime]) AND
       DATEPART(MONTH, e1.[datetime])   = DATEPART(MONTH, e2.[datetime]) AND
       DATEPART(DAY,   e1.[datetime])   = DATEPART(DAY,   e2.[datetime]) AND
       DATEPART(HOUR,  e1.[datetime])   = DATEPART(HOUR,  e2.[datetime]) AND
       DATEPART(MI,    e1.[datetime])/5 = DATEPART(MI,    DATEADD(MI, -1, e2.[datetime]))/5
     ORDER BY
       [datetime] DESC
  ) AS [Close],
  MIN(ExchangeRate) AS low,
  MAX(ExchangeRate) AS high
FROM
  exchangetable e1
GROUP BY 
  DATEPART(YEAR,  [datetime]),
  DATEPART(MONTH, [datetime]),
  DATEPART(DAY,   [datetime]),
  DATEPART(HOUR,  [datetime]),
  DATEPART(mi,    [datetime])/5
```

Oh and BTW I needed to add an Hour datepart otherwise you'll find "TimeBrackets" from different parts of the day aggregating together. Your data produces the following result with this query:

```
Year    Month   Day Hour    TimeBracket Open    Close   low    high
2015    1        1    0     0           0.70    0.75    0.69    0.78
2015    1        1    0     1           0.75    0.80    0.75    0.80
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DENSE_RANK()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` with `PARTITION BY` to get what you are looking for. Something like this.

Explanation of code:

- `DENSE_RANK()` allocates a distinct Grp based on current date,hour and minute / 5.
- 1st `ROW_NUMBER` allocates unique a number within a grp starting from 1 based on increasing time. If this number is 1 then that row is the first row in the grp
- 2st `ROW_NUMBER` allocates unique a number within a grp starting from 1 based on decreasing time. If this number is 1 then that row is the last row in the grp

**Query**

```
;WITH exchangetable(Pair, [Time], Price) AS (
SELECT 'USD-AUD', '2015-1-1 00:01', 0.70 
UNION ALL SELECT'USD-AUD', '2015-1-1 00:02', 0.73  
UNION ALL SELECT'USD-AUD', '2015-1-1 00:03', 0.69  
UNION ALL SELECT'USD-AUD', '2015-1-1 00:04', 0.78  
UNION ALL SELECT'USD-AUD', '2015-1-1 00:05', 0.75
UNION ALL SELECT'USD-AUD', '2015-1-1 00:06', 0.80
), Grp as 
(
Select
DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,[Time]),DATEPART(HOUR, [Time]),(DATEPART(mi, [Time]) / 5)) grp,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CONVERT(DATE,[Time]),DATEPART(HOUR, [Time]),(DATEPART(mi, [Time]) / 5) ORDER BY [Time]) f_row,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CONVERT(DATE,[Time]),DATEPART(HOUR, [Time]),(DATEPART(mi, [Time]) / 5) ORDER BY [Time] DESC) l_row,*
from exchangetable
)
SELECT G1.*,G_First.*,G_Last.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT grp,MAX(Price) max_price,MIN(Price) min_price
    FROM Grp
    GROUP BY grp
) G1
INNER JOIN Grp G_Last ON G_Last.grp = G1.grp AND G_Last.l_row = 1
INNER JOIN Grp G_First ON G_First.grp = G1.grp AND G_First.f_row = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH exchangetable(idn,Pair, [Time], Price) AS (
SELECT 1,'USD-AUD', '2015-1-1 00:01', 0.70 
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'USD-AUD', '2015-1-1 00:02', 0.73  
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'USD-AUD', '2015-1-1 00:03', 0.69  
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'USD-AUD', '2015-1-1 00:04', 0.78  
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'USD-AUD', '2015-1-1 00:05', 0.75
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'USD-AUD', '2015-1-1 00:06', 0.80
UNION ALL SELECT 7,'USD-AUD', '2015-1-1 00:07', 0.78
)
,
CTE_Open
AS
(
select DATEPART(minute,[Time])/6 id,price from exchangetable where [Time]
in(
select MIN([Time])
from exchangetable t
group by PAIR,DATEPART(minute,[Time])/6
)
),
CTE_Close
AS
(
select DATEPART(minute,[Time])/6 id,price from exchangetable where [Time]
in(
select MAX([Time])
from exchangetable t
group by PAIR,DATEPART(minute,[Time])/6
)
)
select t.PAIR,MIN(t2.price) OpenPrice,MAX(t.Price) MaxPrice,Min(t.Price) MinPrice,MIN(t3.Price) as ClosePrice
from exchangetable t join CTE_OPen t2
on (DATEPART(minute,[Time])/6)=t2.id
join CTE_Close t3
on (DATEPART(minute,[Time])/6)=t3.id
group by t.PAIR,DATEPART(minute,[Time])/6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that avoids joins is to use

```
DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [exchangetable].[Time]) / 5 * 5, 0)
```

as our windowing period, and then to use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY` on the analytic functions, since we order the items by `[Time]` which we do not want part of the grouping.

```
;WITH [exchangetable] ([Pair], [Time], [Price]) AS (
    SELECT
        'USD-AUD',
        '2015-1-1 00:01',
        0.70
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'USD-AUD',
        '2015-1-1 00:02',
        0.73
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'USD-AUD',
        '2015-1-1 00:03',
        0.69
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'USD-AUD',
        '2015-1-1 00:04',
        0.78
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'USD-AUD',
        '2015-1-1 00:05',
        0.75
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'USD-AUD',
        '2015-1-1 00:06',
        0.80
),
      [periods] AS (
    SELECT
        [PeriodNo] = DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [exchangetable].[Time]) / 5 * 5, 0),
        [exchangetable].[Pair],
        [exchangetable].[Time],
        [exchangetable].[Price]
    FROM [exchangetable]
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       [periods].[Pair],
       [periods].[PeriodNo],
       [StartTime] = FIRST_VALUE([periods].[Time]) OVER (PARTITION BY
                                                             [periods].[Pair],
                                                             [periods].[PeriodNo]
                                                         ORDER BY [periods].[Time]
                                                   ),
       [EndTime] = LAST_VALUE([periods].[Time]) OVER (PARTITION BY
                                                          [periods].[Pair],
                                                          [periods].[PeriodNo]
                                                      ORDER BY [periods].[Time]
                                                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                                                ),
       [StartVal] = FIRST_VALUE([periods].[Price]) OVER (PARTITION BY
                                                             [periods].[Pair],
                                                             [periods].[PeriodNo]
                                                         ORDER BY [periods].[Time]
                                                   ),
       [EndVal] = LAST_VALUE([periods].[Price]) OVER (PARTITION BY
                                                          [periods].[Pair],
                                                          [periods].[PeriodNo]
                                                      ORDER BY [periods].[Time]
                                                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                                                )
FROM [periods];
```